# how to use begin() in a subfunction?

Tags: casperjs

Is this the right way to use the new `begin()` feature from casperjs dev-1.1-beta?
Do i really have to use a new begin() function in my thenClick function?
Is it correct how i used `test.done()`?

When i run my test it returns `dubious: neuen Teilnehmer anlegen: 2 tests planned, 1 tests executed`.

```
casper.test.begin('neuen Teilnehmer anlegen', 2, function(test) {
    test.assertExists('a[href="/rdgRC/CommunityService/new"]');
    casper.thenClick('a[href="/rdgRC/CommunityService/new"]', function () {  
        casper.test.begin('page is found', 1, function(test) {
            test.assertUrlMatch(/rdgRC\/CommunityService\/new/, 'Redirected to index page after login');  
            test.done();
        });
        test.done();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like:

```
casper.test.begin('neuen Teilnehmer anlegen', 2, function suite(test) {

     test.assertExists('a[href="/rdgRC/CommunityService/new"]');

     casper.thenClick('a[href="/rdgRC/CommunityService/new"]', function () { 
          test.assertUrlMatch(/rdgRC\/CommunityService\/new/, 'Redirected to index page after login');     
     });

     casper.run(function() {
          test.done();
     });
});
```

You might want to wrap the tests inside a capser.start(url, function() {}); if you are looking to load a page.  Hope this helps!